# How much fuel cost will be incurred for transporting 4000kg of cargo via Mi-17 helicopter for 54 km?

Tags: military, helicopter, cost, fuel-consumption

I am working on a logistics case study in which I am using Mi-17 helicopters for transportation of relief to the affected areas in a disaster.

In this regard, I want to check my estimates with the actual operational experience from the community..

Comment: The question title specifies ***fuel*** costs, but those are probably among these least of the costs of a project like this. What about maintenance costs? What about paying for the use of the machine, pilots, crew, etc? Any operational experience will tell you as much about these costs as about merely the fuel cost in isolation.

Comment: Actually I am finding it difficult for determining the maintenance cost (hourly), can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you help me in setting the maintenance cost per flight hour with some reference? I am getting numbers from ChatGPT but I cannot cite them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.army-technology.com/projects/mi8t/) source, the Mil Mi-17 does about 465-495km at standard load with the 1870l internal fuel. This equates to around 4l/km.

[Currently](https://jet-a1-fuel.com/price/united-states), the fuel price for a liter of jet A1 in the US is $0.559. Therefore:

$54km \cdot 4 \frac{l}{km} \cdot  0.559 \frac{$}{l}  \approx \\\$120 $

Comment: On such a short hop, the takeoff and landing add a substantial amount of fuel consumption. I bet I'm not too far off to say you could almost double the cost. Helicopters are super inefficient in vertical flight.

Comment: So can you give an estimate based on some reference